# Exit terminal after running a bash script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am trying to write a `bash` script to open certain files (mostly pdf files) using the `gnome-open` command. I also want the terminal to exit once it opens the pdf file.

I have tried adding `exit` to the end of my script however that does not close the terminal. I did try to search online for an answer to my question but I couldn't find any proper one, I would really appreciate it if you guys could help.

I need an answer that only kills the terminal from which I run the command not all the terminals would this be possible? The previous answer which I accepted kills all the terminal windows that are open. I did not realize this was the case until today.

Comment: Are you running the script in the terminal in the first place? Strictly from command line, there is no reason to open the terminal to do so.

Comment: Yes I run the script from the terminal. I didnt realize there was a difference between terminal and command line

Comment: I replaced the `gnome-open` with `xdg-open` in my script but there is no change. The terminal still remains open

Comment: @Tim Wow, it works =) +1

Comment: @Tim But my solution was not bad either. ;)

Comment: @Tim yes, thats true. :\

Comment: Are you using the script to open just one file? Or are you using it to open multiple files?

Comment: I only open one file at a time

Comment: @RumeshSudhaharan Ok, I updated my answer

Comment: I have a script that opens two other terminal windows with the & character appended so they stay open independently.  However, the exit at the end of the script gets ignored.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you're opening just one file, you don't *really* need to use a script, because a script is meant to be an easy way to run multiple commands in a row, while here you just need to run two commands (including `exit`).

If you want to run `exit` after a command or after a chain of commands, you can chain it to what you have already by using the `&&` operator (which on success of the previous command / chain of commands will execute the next command) or by using the `;` operator (which both on success and on failure of the previous command / chain of commands will execute the next command).

In this case it would be something like that:

```
gnome-open <path_to_pdf_file> && exit
```

<sub>*<path_to_pfd_file> = path of the pdf file</sub>

`exit` put at the end of a script doesn't work because it just exits the `bash` instance in which the script is run, which is another `bash` instance than the Terminal's inner `bash` instance.

If you want to use a script anyway, the most straightforward way it's to just call the script like so:

```
<path_to_script> && exit
```

Or if the script is in the Terminal's current working directory like so:

```
./<script> && exit
```

If you *really* don't want to / can't do that, the second most straightforward way is to add this line at the end of your script:

```
kill -9 $PPID
```

This will send a `SIGKILL` signal to the to the script's parent process (the `bash` instance linked to the Terminal). If only one `bash` instance is linked to the Terminal, that being killed will cause Terminal to close itself. If multiple `bash` instances are linked to the Terminal, that being killed won't cause Terminal to close itself.

Comment: The SIGTERM signal is sent to a process to request its termination. Unlike the SIGKILL signal, it can be caught and interpreted or ignored by the process. This allows the process to perform nice termination releasing resources and saving state if appropriate. SIGINT is nearly identical to SIGTERM.

Comment: @A.B. You're right, `SIGTERM` here is not enough.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess ill just use the single command you gave in your answer

Comment: kill $PPID does the same as exit - nothing.  And kill -9 $PPID closes all the child windows along with the parent.

Comment: +1 for use of `kill -9 $PPID` When using the GUI option "Run in Konsole" in Debian 11, terminal does not close when using a plan old `exit`

Answer (score 8):

#### You can use `exec ./your-script`.

A terminal emulator like GNOME Terminal quits when the initial process running inside it--which is usually a shell--quits.

If you are already in a terminal and the only thing you want to do before quitting that terminal is to run a particular script (or program), then this means you no longer really need the shell that's running in it anymore. Thus you can use the shell's `exec` builtin to make the shell *replace itself* with the process created by your command.

- In the case of your script, that's another shell process--just as how a *second* shell process is created when you run a script without `exec`.

The syntax is `exec command`, e.g., `exec ./your-script`.

#### `exec`: an Example

For example, suppose I have a shell script called `count`, marked executable, and located in the current directory. It contains:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
for i in {5..1}; do echo $i; sleep 1; done
```

And, in a terminal, I run:

```
exec ./count
```

This prints the numerals `5`, `4`, `3`, `2`, and `1`, one per second, and then the terminal window closes.

If you run this from something other than the first process run in your terminal--for example, if you ran `bash` first to start another shell instance--then this brings you back to the shell that created *that* process, rather than quitting the terminal. (This caveat applies equally to `exit`-based methods.)

#### You can use `./your-script; exit`.

If you don't want to tell your shell to replace itself with the new process (via `exec`), you can tell it to stick around but quit itself immediately after the new process finishes.

To do this, run your command and the `exit` command, separated by `;` so they can be given on one line.

The syntax is `command; exit`, e.g., `./your-script; exit`.

#### `command; exit` vs. `command && exit`

You may notice this looks similar to the `./your-script && exit` method suggested in [kos's](https://askubuntu.com/a/611687/22949) and [heemayl's](https://askubuntu.com/a/611699/22949) answers. The difference is that:

- `&&` runs the second command only if the first command [reported that it succeeded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status) by returning an exit code of zero.
- `;` runs the second command regardless of whether or not the first command reported success.

Which one you want depends on the specific situation. If the command fails, do you want the calling shell (and hosting terminal) to stay up? If so, use `&&`; if not, use `;`.

There is also `command || exit`, which quits the calling shell only if *`command`* reported *failure*.

Answer (score 6):

This script terminates the terminal and thus the shell and himself.

*It  mercilessly kills all processes. If you have multiple tabs open in a terminal, then these are also closed.*

*The problem is, if several terminals are opened and these are child processes of `gnome-terminal-server`, all terminals will be killed.*

*In this case, the script should be started in an independent terminal, eg `xterm`*

```
<your_command> & disown

PPPID=$(awk '{print $4}' "/proc/$PPID/stat")
kill $PPPID
```

- PPID

  The PPID is the parent process id, in this case the shell (`e.g. /bin/bash`)
- PPPID

  The PPPID is the parent process id of PPID, in this case, the terminal window
- `<your_command> & disown`

  In the bash shell, the disown builtin command is used to remove jobs from the job table, or to mark jobs so that a SIGHUP signal is not sent to them if the parent shell receives it (e.g. if the user logs out).
- `awk '{print $4}' "/proc/$PPID/stat"`

  Gets the value of the fourth column of the file `/proc/$PPID/stat` (e.g. for `/proc/1/stat` it returns 0)

Comment: I think the command $$ get's the pid of the terminal... Would that be an alternative? Could you also explain how to disown?

Comment: How does this script do that? I am still new to shell scripting so I cant really understand those commands.  Could you please explain how it closes the terminal

Comment: @Tim No, it returns the shell in a terminal: `ps xa | grep $$` =>
 `4381 pts/0    Ss     0:01 /usr/bin/zsh`

Comment: @A.B. Thanks for updating your answer. Are you sure that this method is safe? I recall reading somewhere that killing the terminal in this method is not advisable. I couldn't find where I read that so I may be wrong but I would just like to clarify that it is safe to run this command

Comment: @RumeshSudhaharan The command mercilessly kills all processes. If you have multiple tabs open in a terminal, then these are also closed.

Comment: @A.B. So the command will only kill other tabs? if I have multiple terminal windows open, will it only kill the one from which I run the script or all the windows? I'm sorry if I disturb you by asking so many questions

Comment: @RumeshSudhaharan It kills the entire terminal window in which the script is started, but no other terminal windows.

Comment: @A.B. Thanks I just tried your suggestion it works really well. you just saved me a lot work :)

Comment: @RumeshSudhaharan You're welcome :)

Comment: @A.B. There's no need to put the process in the background and to disown it, because `gnome-open` runs in the background and unlinked from the Terminal already

Comment: @A.B. you previously said that this only kills the current terminal window and not any of the others.  I used this script today with two terminal windows open and both of them were killed once I ran the script.

Comment: @RumeshSudhaharan I will check it

Comment: @RumeshSudhaharan same here, bad test. Give me a second.

Comment: @RumeshSudhaharan Yes, the parent process is the gnome-terminal-server. And that kills all terminal. Sorry for that.

Comment: @RumeshSudhaharan I have posted a workaround.

Comment: @A.B. Thanks for the reply though I would prefer to use the normal terminal because of the easy shortcut. One of the other answers works properly for me so I guess ill use that one

Comment: Great job! I really appreciate this answer for the explanations. It helped me to understand more of Linux.

Answer (score 4):

You could source your script instead of running it e.g

```
$ cat run.sh
exit;
$ ./run.sh #will not close
$ . ./run.sh # will close
```

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would execute the command to open pdf or other files in subshell, put a delay to let the files open, and then exit. Basically, here's what I've tested `(nohup gnome-open *.pdf &); sleep 2; exit`

Variation on this would be `nohup gnome-open *.pdf && sleep 2 && exit`

Comment: In my case, since `nohup` ignores the hangup signal, `nohup xdg-open some_program` worked for me, and `exit` was unneeded. `nohup` redirects message to a `nohup.out` file: `nohup: ignoring input and appending output to nohup.out`

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be:

```
xdg-open file.pdf && exit
```

Unlike other similar command `nohup` is not needed to make the command ignoring `SIGHUP`, the reason being `xdg-open` will exit spawning a child process which is preferred application to open the pdf file. As the actual process started from the terminal is no longer there to be killed, `nohup` is not needed.

`&&` indicates the next command will be run if the previous command is successful i.e. returns the exit code `0` (`$?=0`) and `exit` will simply close the terminal.

Comment: I think he said exit wasn't working...

Comment: @Tim: Perhaps OP did not use it the right way, from the question its very unclear to me how did he/she put `exit` at the end and did not work..

Comment: @Tim Because OP put `exit` inside the script, which is unuseful because it has the effect of exiting the `bash` instance in which the script is being executed rather then the parent `bash` instance (the one linked to the Terminal), which would cause the Terminal to close instead

Comment: Anyway `xdg-open` runs already in the background and unlinked from the the Terminal, so you don't need `nohup` here, plus from what I understand OP runs `xdg-open` multiple times inside a script to batch-open multiple files, using `xdg-open` like that inside the script would cause the script to exit at the first `xdg-open` occurence

Comment: @kos: No, i am not running `xdg-open` in the backgr, even if i had `nohup` is for a different reason & must be there..any background process from originating terminal will be killed when you will kill the parent terminal..`nohup` is there to prevent it..as i don't need to use the terminal interactively again, there is no need to put the process in bg..on your 2nd point that can also be prevented by running each `xdg-open && exit` in a subshell..

Comment: There's no need for `nohup`, just try `touch test.txt && xdg-open test.txt && exit`, the Terminal will be closed and `gedit` will stay opened. My second point was about the fact that OP has a script with multiple `xdg-open` commands, and running each of them chained with `exit` will cause the script to exit at the first occurence

Comment: @kos I think you are confused between `&` and `&&`..try running `gedit test.txt && exit`......`xdg-open test.txt && exit` works because `xdg-open` will open the file with the preferred application and then the terminal will exit with `xdg-open` being the process being killed (check that with `ps`) leaving the `gedit` or whatever the preferred app open..(although i need to work on this explanation in details)..

Comment: No I'm not confused between `&` and `&&`, try `touch test.txt && xdg-open test.txt && jobs -l`, there's no background process for `xdg-open`, so it doesn't need either `& disown` or `nohup`

Comment: @kos First of all, could you please check what command i have used, there is no `&` in my command, secondly in my last comment i think i have answered your last question (why there is no `xdg-open` & why you can work without `nohup` in this particular case)..also `nohup` is for different reason as i have already mentioned..

Comment: Sorry, my latest example was wrong, but I've never stated there's an `&` in your command... In your last comment you said "`xdg-open test.txt && exit` works because xdg-open will open the file with the preferred application and then the terminal will exit with xdg-open being the process being killed", what I'm trying to say it's that xdg-open is not getting killed, because it exits on his own once it has done what it had to, so it's unuseful to use either `& disown` (which you didn't do) or to use `nohup` (which is what you did)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23027/discussion-between-heemayl-and-kos).

Answer (score 1):

To explicitly answer the title question,

**"Exit terminal after running a bash script"**:

### Run only your script in the terminal

Without looking at the details what the script does, a script can be directly run inside a terminal with the option `-e` (`--command`), without starting a shell - it is used instead of the shell then:

```
gnome-terminal -e ./script.sh
```

Use the option `-x` (`--execute`) when you want to provide arguments to the script. With this, just the whole remainder of the commandline is taken as command and arguments.

```
gnome-terminal -x ./script.sh foo bar
```

If your script exits, there is no interactive shell that could hold up anything by waiting for user input.

### Examples

The teminal will just exit after the command running in it exits - like this, closing after `sleep` has run 4 seconds, with no shell:

```
gnome-terminal -x sleep 4
```

Of course, you can stil use shell scripting, because your script is using a different shell instance anyway.

Also, you can run a shell with an explicit script - it will not be interactive:

```
gnome-terminal -x bash -c "echo 'Hello!'; sleep 4"
```

Answer (score 0):

With "When script exits, close terminal" in the terminal settings, I place this at the bottom of an executable bash script to close it:

```
echo "Automatically Closing in 3 seconds..."

sleep 3

exit

read # show terminal output
```

When I put the exit after the read, script and terminal window don't close.

Another nice one that I often use to reload a script from its startpoint in the same terminal:

```
echo "Enter = Restart"
echo "Ctrl+c or Close button to Close"

read

exec bash "$0" "$@" # Restart script from the beginning
```

Here the restarting rule follows 'read'.

Cheerio.